# NAT MASQUERADE response packets not coming back into private network

Tags: ubuntu, nat

I setup NAT for my Xen VM inside a real host, so the VM essentially forms its private network with the virtual NIC inside the host.

so the network is like this:

[ (VM 10.0.0.3) ---- bridge 10.0.0.1  ---- real NIC 192.168.0.105] ------- internet

now I set  up NAT by the steps in http://blog.manula.org/2012/04/manually-configuring-nat-networking-in.html

from inside VM, I ran "ping a_real_internet_IP "  , the issue is that the ping does not produce responses. I ran "tcpdump" on the traffic going out on the NIC, and see packets masquerading as  src=192.168.0.105,dst=a_real_internet_IP. so this shows that the MASQUERADE is working. **I also see the response packets with reversed src and dst.**

but the issue is that on the bridge, I only see packets src=10.0.0.3,dst=a_real_internet_IP, **and not the returning packets** .  since the response packets are seen on the NIC, but not on this virtual bridge, where are they dropped?

I tried to put in some TRACE, but TRACE only works on raw table, not the nat table.

weirdly the same setup works fine on my desktop server, but not on my laptop. the former runs ubuntu 20, while the latter ubuntu 18, not sure if this mattered at all. but NAT is a very basic network setup, both systems should have respected it.

Answer (score 0):

resolved, docker messed up the iptables. even though I did "iptables -F && iptables -X " for all rules, it's still the same, I had to remove docker and reboot